# Cannot fide modules gulp

Tags: visual-studio-code, gulp

How can i fix this problem? Im usin VSCode  and trying to install gulp in my project. What`s the problem ot this?

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
```

gulpfile.js

```
import { src, dest } from 'gulp';
import sass from 'gulp-sass';
import minifyCSS from 'gulp-csso';


function style() {
    return src('./scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(dest('./css'))
}

const _style = style;
export { _style as style };
```

terminal code: gulp _style

Comment: show your code that you have used

Comment: updated header already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

node --experimental-modules gulpfile.js and after it works
and change gulpfile.js to this type

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const minifyCSS = require('gulp-csso');


function style() {
    return gulp.src('./scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
}

exports.style = style;
```